# Focus to new element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay so in my website I want to make it so when I click on a certain div it will display new information. For example if the div text said "What is your name?" I want to be able to click on it and it to say "My name is ...". Thank you in advance. Also just a note, I do not care what programming language I have to do this in.

Here are all my documents so far with my attempts.

```css
body {
 margin 0;
 padding 0;
 font-family: sans-serif, arial;
}



header {
 background: #00795f;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 40px 0;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
}

nav ul {
 background-color: #43a286;
 overflow: hidden;
 color: white;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
 -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s;
 -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s;
 -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s;
 -o-transition: max-height 0.4s;
 transition: max-height 0.4s;

}

nav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 20px;
}

nav ul li:hover {
 background-color: #399077;
}

section {
 line-height: 1.5em;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 padding: 40px;
 width: 75%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.handle {
 width: 100%;
 background: #005c48;
 text-align: left;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 15px 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: white;
 display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
 nav ul {
  max-height: 0px;
 }

 .showing {
  max-height: 20em;
 }

 nav ul li {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 .handle {
  display: block;
 }



}

.first-info {
 background-color: #43a286;
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 border-radius: 20px;
}

.first-info-text {
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 font-size: 20px;
 border-radius: 20px;
}

.first-info-text p {
 margin: 5px;
}

.first-info:hover {
 background-color: #399077;
 cursor: pointer;
} 

.first-info-text:hover {
 background-color: #399077;
 cursor: pointer;
} 

.switch {
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 font-size: 20px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 display: none;
}

.first-info:focus { 

 .first-info-text {
  display: none;
 }

 .switch {
  display: all;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   Lorem Ipsum
  </header>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <a href="#"><li>Lorem </li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Lorem</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Lorem</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Lorem</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Lorem</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Lorem</li></a> 
    <a href="#"><li>Lorem</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li></li>Lorem</a>
   </ul>
   <div class="handle">Menu</div>
  </nav>
  <section>
   <div class="first-info">
    <div class="first-info-text">
     <p>What is my name?</p>
     <div class="switch">
      <p>bob!</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
  <script>
   $('.handle').on('click', function(){
    $('nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
   })
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no this is not a joke

Comment: Then I guess you need to be told that this isn't a code writing service. If you've made an attempt and got stuck, post what you've tried and ask about the specific problem. Giving a list of requirements just isn't going to cut it.

Comment: Okay Thank You I am Making The Edit Now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will be useful

You wont need to add $(document).ready(function(){..... if it is bottom of body tag

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#first-info').on('click', function(){
   $('nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
   $('.first-info-text').toggleClass('switch');
   }) 

})
```

I have removed the p tags and have added span tag from mark up

HTML

```
<header>
            Lorem Ipsum
        </header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <a href="#"><li>Lorem </li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Lorem</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Lorem</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Lorem</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Lorem</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Lorem</li></a>  
                <a href="#"><li>Lorem</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li></li>Lorem</a>
            </ul>
            <div class="handle">Menu</div>
        </nav>
        <section>
      <div class ="first-info" id="first-info">
        <span class='first-info-text'>What is your name</span>
        <span class='first-info-text msgInfo switch'>My name is Bob</span>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Modified CSS

```
body {
    margin 0;
    padding 0;
    font-family: sans-serif, arial;
}



header {
    background: #00795f;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

nav ul {
    background-color: #43a286;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.4s;
    transition: max-height 0.4s;

}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #399077;
}

section {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.handle {
    width: 100%;
    background: #005c48;
    text-align: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
    nav ul {
        max-height: 0px;
    }

    .showing {
        max-height: 20em;
    }

    nav ul li {
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 15px;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 15px 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .handle {
        display: block;
    }



}

.first-info {
    background-color: #43a286;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.first-info-text {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.first-info-text p {
    margin: 5px;
}

.first-info:hover {
    background-color: #399077;
    cursor: pointer;
} 

.first-info-text:hover {
    background-color: #399077;
    cursor: pointer;
} 

.switch {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: none;
}

.first-info:focus { }

.switch {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

You didnt closed this css declaration `.first-info:focus`

Here is [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/d1r7w73x/2/)